snowflake recursive query output
Here is my sample data table :
create or replace table test_case (
col_a string,
col_b string,
match_flag string);

insert into test_case
(col_a, col_b, match_flag)
values
('a', 'b', 'Y'),
('b', 'c', 'Y'),
('c', 'a', 'Y'),
('a', 'z', 'N');

As you can see, the values in col_a , col_b is considered a match if match_flag='Y'. First three rows are considered a match. As in first row, 'a' is match to 'b'. similarly, 2nd and 3rd row gives, 'b' is match to 'c' and 'c' is match to 'a'.
I am trying to write a query which outputs a concatenation of values for all matches. For example, in the above case,  I am looking for following output:



col_a
col_b
col_c
output




a
b
'Y'
'a-b-c'


b
c
'Y'
'a-b-c'


c
a
'Y'
'a-b-c'


a
z
'N'
'na'



My query seems to going to infinite loop.
WITH RECURSIVE match_cte AS (
    -- Base case: start with the first row where match_flag = 'Y'
    SELECT col_a, col_b, col_a AS start_col, col_b AS match_path
    FROM test_case
    WHERE match_flag = 'Y'
    
    UNION ALL
    
    -- Recursive case: find matches for the current match_path and continue
    SELECT t.col_a, t.col_b, m.start_col, 
           CASE 
               WHEN m.match_path LIKE '%' || t.col_a || '%' THEN m.match_path
               ELSE m.match_path || '-' || t.col_b 
           END AS match_path
    FROM match_cte m
    JOIN test_case t ON m.col_b = t.col_a
    WHERE t.match_flag = 'Y'
)

-- Final output with results for each original row in the table
SELECT t.col_a, t.col_b, t.match_flag,
       CASE 
           WHEN t.match_flag = 'Y' THEN 
               (SELECT DISTINCT match_path 
                FROM match_cte m 
                WHERE m.start_col = t.col_a 
                ORDER BY LENGTH(m.match_path) DESC LIMIT 1)
           ELSE 'na'
       END AS output
FROM test_case t;

Any thoughts on how I can achieve the desired output ?

Hi apologies, should your desired output not be in this order, I think a-b-c , b-c-a and c-a-b. I maybe wrong but let me know thanks!

Take all Childs(matches) for every col_a, then aggregate Childs with order.
See example
WITH RECURSIVE match_cte AS (
    -- Base case: start with the first row where match_flag = 'Y'
    SELECT 0 lvl,col_a, col_a col_b
    FROM test_case
    WHERE match_flag = 'Y'
    
    UNION ALL
    
    -- Recursive case: find matches for the current match_path and continue
    SELECT lvl+1,m.col_a, t.col_b
    FROM match_cte m
    JOIN test_case t ON m.col_b = t.col_a
    WHERE t.match_flag = 'Y' and t.col_b<>m.col_a
     and lvl<10.  -- for debug only
)
-- Final output with results for each original row in the table
select t.*
  ,case when t.match_flag='Y' then match_path
   else 'na'
   end match_path
from test_case t
left join(
  SELECT t.col_a, listagg(distinct col_b ,'-')within group( order by col_b) match_path
  FROM match_cte t
  group by col_a
) c on c.col_a=t.col_a ;




col_a
col_b
match_flag
match_path




a
b
Y
a-b-c


b
c
Y
a-b-c


c
a
Y
a-b-c


a
z
N
na



fiddle (postgresql).
Difference in string_agg ->listagg.

we meet again...

Yes)! Glad to see you

The infinite loop issue you are having in the code is from your recursive query because the logic doesn't effectively terminate. The function just allows the query to keep appending to the match path even after the cycle should be closed, giving you the infinite loop
Code is tested:
Here is a dbfiddle link to see result dbfiddle
WITH RECURSIVE match_cte AS (
    SELECT col_a, col_b, col_a AS start_col, 
           col_a || '-' || col_b AS match_path,
           ARRAY[col_a || '-' || col_b] AS visited_pairs
    FROM test_case
    WHERE match_flag = 'Y'
    
    UNION ALL
    
match_path and continue
    SELECT t.col_a, t.col_b, m.start_col, 
           CASE 
               WHEN POSITION(t.col_b IN m.match_path) > 0 THEN m.match_path
               ELSE m.match_path || '-' || t.col_b 
           END AS match_path,
           ARRAY_APPEND(m.visited_pairs, t.col_a || '-' || t.col_b) AS visited_pairs
    FROM match_cte m
    JOIN test_case t ON m.col_b = t.col_a
    WHERE t.match_flag = 'Y'
    AND NOT (t.col_a || '-' || t.col_b) = ANY(m.visited_pairs)
)

SELECT t.col_a, t.col_b, t.match_flag,
       CASE 
           WHEN t.match_flag = 'Y' THEN 
               (SELECT match_path 
                FROM match_cte m 
                WHERE m.start_col = t.col_a 
                ORDER BY LENGTH(m.match_path) DESC LIMIT 1)
           ELSE 'na'
       END AS output
FROM test_case t;

